# I keep getting cannot resolve method ' setText(java.lang.string) error

Tags: java, android

I can't seem to get my set text lines to work.I'm trying to press a button that would clear the text views.

```
            btnClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
            btnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){

                    txtBox1 = (EditText) findViewById(editText9);
                    editText9.setText("");
                    txtBox2 = (EditText) findViewById(editText10);
                    editText10.setText("");

                }
            });

            btnClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
            txtBox2 = (EditText) findViewById(editText10);

            btnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v){

                    txtBox2 = (EditText) findViewById(editText10);
                    editText10.setText("");
                    String s = new String(binary);
                    txtBox1.setText(s);
```

Comment: im a little confused, you get your editText9 as txtBox1 and then you never use it. Just use txtBox1.setText("");

Comment: You want to clear your editText in the textbox when user hits the button??

Comment: What is `editText9` and does it actually have `setText` method? Isn't it an int or something?

Answer (score 0):

I see two things here that I think could help. First is this line:

```
txtBox2 = (EditText) findViewById(editText10);
```

The argument you're passing to `findViewById()` is probably of type `int`. Normally you'd use an `R.id` constant, but there's no technical reason you have to. So we can conclude that `editText10` is an int.

Then there are these two lines:

```
txtBox2 = (EditText) findViewById(editText10);
editText10.setText("");
```

These read like you're trying to clear the text in `txtBox2`, but you're calling the `setText()` method on the wrong variable. Perhaps you can replace `editText10.setText("")` with `txtBox2.setText("")`.

Anyway, the reason you're getting this error is that the object you're calling `setText()` on isn't a `TextView`. I suspect it is an `int`, but it could be something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize view before you use it. Otherwise, it will be null.
You have initialized `btnClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);` after setting the `onClickListener` for it. It won't work actually.

Make sure all the view initialize before you use it.

Best way of implementation is initializing all the view's first then use it

Your implementation should be like this:

```
            txtBox2 = (EditText) findViewById(editText10);
            txtBox1 = (EditText) findViewById(editText9);
            btnClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);

              btnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v){ 
                        editText9.setText("");
                        editText10.setText("");
                    }
                });

                btnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v){
                        editText10.setText("");
                        String s = new String(binary);
                        txtBox1.setText(s);
```

Comment: Happy coding :)

Answer (score -1):

You're clearing an edit text not a textView

try `txtBox2.getText().clear();`